# Space usage analyser for Dropbox?

Tags: webapp-rec, dropbox

Is there a web application (similar to WinDirStat, Baobab, etc...) for analysing space usage in your Dropbox?

I realise that it would be possible to do by syncing the Dropbox to a computer, then running one of the aforementioned programs on the folder, but I have a large Dropbox, and use "Selective Sync" to not download everything to every computer.

Is there anything available that does this?

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here, but your question is very welcome here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The only unofficial tool I'm aware of that can do this now (2017) is an Android app:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.unclouded

Back in 2013:

Two new applications that do this were revealed in [this Hacker News discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6735872):

1. https://mkolysh.scripts.mit.edu/whatsinthebox (working app)
   2013-11-15
2. https://github.com/kevincon/utilityknife (source code)
   2013-09-13

Due to the nature of the DropBox API, they will require full access.

> Once you've tried it and got your treemap, you can unauthorize the app
>   from https://www.dropbox.com/account/security#applications

Comment: Sadly first one is not working now :(

Comment: @Korayem I verified the first link (whatsinthebox) worked today; obviously there are lot of possible points where connectivity could (temporarily) break at any time but 'it worked for me'!

Comment: https://github.com/kevincon/utilityknife is not working after allowing access

Comment: whatsinthebox 404s now.

Answer (score -1):

There is currently no way to do so from a web application. The most you can do is use Dropbox itself to view the data used.